# JQuery : mouseover open a lightbox but mouseout can't close it correctly

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox as a lightbox on one of my website.
I have been able to make it opening a lightbox when my mouse is over a picture, but I can't make it close the lightbox when my mouse leave the same picture.

As soon as my lightbox is opened if I move my mouse, the mouseleave event is trigerred event is my mouse is still on the picture.

Here is a JSfiddle to show you my issue :
http://jsfiddle.net/8ByeT/1/

Do you have any idea on how to solve that?

Thanks and Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ByeT/15/

Updates:

css: overlaying div display set to none, so it won't trigger mouse leave event

JS: added initial width and height for colorbox, so the appearing image won't cover your image.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot I don't know exactly how it work now. But it work. THanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two copies of jQuery loaded in your fiddle.

You have two on ready event handlers:

`$(function() {`

and

`$(document).ready(function() {`

but the real issue seems to be that you have a mouseleave event handler, that gets fired when something appears OVER it, then another event fires that makes it apper again and cycle somehow.

Difficult to tell but you might have some included javascript that is firing in your fiddle also.  I will leave digging into that to you.

I must assume that the unmatched tag: `</section>` is some  kind of paste issue into the fiddle.