# colorbox mouseover position

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) for displaying images in overlays. I want to display the images on mouseover event. from another question on stackoverflow I have got the code to work with mouseover ([JQuery : mouseover open a lightbox but mouseout can't close it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914186/jquery-mouseover-open-a-lightbox-but-mouseout-cant-close-it-correctly)). Now I want to display the colorbox overlay on the side of the image over which I place the mouse (either left or right side of the image depending on the space on the window but not centered on the window). I am finding no way to do this. I am very amateur in JQuery. Please help.

Here is my working code for colorbox with mouseover event:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.gallery").colorbox().mouseover(function(){ 

            $(this).click();

            });         


    $('a.gallery').mouseleave(function(){
             $.colorbox.close();
        });    
    }); 

</script>
```

here is my mark up:

```
<div class="mygallery">             

<a class='gallery' href='images/knitmen/1.jpg'><img src="images/knitmen/1.jpg" alt ="Knit Men" /></a>
<a class='gallery' href='images/knitmen/2.jpg'><img src="images/knitmen/2.jpg" alt ="Knit Men" /></a>
<a class='gallery' href='images/knitmen/3.jpg'><img src="images/knitmen/3.jpg" alt ="Knit Men" /></a>
<a class='gallery' href='images/knitmen/4.jpg'><img src="images/knitmen/4.jpg" alt ="Knit Men" /></a>

</div>
```

thanks and regards.

Comment: It looks like the [ColorBox examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) are popping up a full-screen div that covers the rest of the page.  Is this true with your website?  If so, the div that hides the rest of the website might be obscuring your anchor tags, preventing the mouseleave event from firing (or more accurately, firing too soon).

Comment: thanks. the code that I am using for the mouseover event is working fine. But I am unable to accommodate desired positioning along with the mouseover event.

Comment: Oh, this is a positioning question!  It'll be hard to say without a concrete example, but you'll need to change the standard Colorbox CSS so that you can move it where you need (`position:absolute`) and then use jQuery to set it's position, ala `$('#colorbox').css({left: leftVal, top: topVal});` and calculate the `leftVal` and `topVal` based on the current ".gallery" link.

Comment: Hi richard, thanks for the clue. I tried my best to follow your tips but no code seem to fit with the existing code for mouseover event. please anyone can suggest a working code preferably in jsfiddle please. my objective is to get the poping up image view as in  www.shutterstock.com for example.

Comment: If you want a JSFiddle fix, you should provide an example JSFiddle that's broken.